# Drawing shape - flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a shape using flutter.
[image: shape-1]
[image: shape-2]

I tried to use some solutions but it didn't work. can anyone help thanks

Comment: You can try `ClipPath` or `CustomPaint`

Comment: you can use stack  view and  red color image  in the stack   and  any other set column and  Row Data position to  set  not Crete a   Custom  shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## An solution with ClipPaths, Stacks and ImageFiltered widgets.

This design is challenging to implement, but it is definitely doable. The three parts, the **red shape**, **white bottom border** and **shadow** must be clipped with an `ClipPath`.

- All of these requires an `ClipPath` with a `CustomClipper`, I provide an simplified example, using a cubic curve.

  - But for making an exact path you can investigate the answer in this question, it might be helpful: [How can i make this shape in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71280225/how-can-i-make-this-shape-in-flutter)
- Then there is coordinating the position of these three parts inside a `Stack` widget.

#### Example

```dart
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomHeader extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function() onTap;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final Color borderColor;
  final Color shadowColor;
  final Color splashColor;
  final double height;
  final Widget? child;

  const CustomHeader({
    Key? key,
    required this.height,
    required this.onTap,
    this.child,
    this.backgroundColor = const Color(0xFFD50000),
    this.splashColor = const Color(0xFFCCFFCC),
    this.borderColor = Colors.white,
    this.shadowColor = Colors.black26,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Stack(
      children: [
        // The shadow effect
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 18.0),
          child: ImageFiltered(
            imageFilter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 2, sigmaY: 2),
            child: ClipPath(
              clipper: CustomHeaderClipper(
                  startHeight: height * 0.75,
                  endHeight: height * 0.18
              ),
              child: Container(
                width: width,
                height: height * 0.76,
                color: shadowColor
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),

        // The white border
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
          child: ClipPath(
            clipper: CustomHeaderClipper(
                startHeight: height * 0.75,
                endHeight: height * 0.18
            ),
            child: Container(
                width: width,
                height: height * 0.75,
                color: borderColor,
            ),
          ),
        ),

        // The red shape
        ClipPath(
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
          clipper: CustomHeaderClipper(
              startHeight: height * 0.68,
              endHeight: height * 0.2
          ),
          child: Material(
            color: backgroundColor,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: onTap,
              splashColor: splashColor,
              child: SizedBox(
                  width: width,
                  height: height * 0.8,
                  child: child,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class CustomHeaderClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  final double startHeight;
  final double endHeight;

  const CustomHeaderClipper({
    required this.startHeight,
    required this.endHeight
  });

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    double height = size.height;
    double width = size.width;

    return Path()
      ..moveTo(0, 0)
      ..lineTo(0, startHeight)
      ..cubicTo(width * 0.35, height, width * 0.5, height * 0.4, width, endHeight)
      ..lineTo(width, 0)
      ..lineTo(0, 0)
      ..close();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}

class CustomHeaderBackgroundScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomHeaderBackgroundScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.2;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      body: SafeArea(
        child: CustomHeader(
          height: height,
          onTap: () {},
          child: const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text("Your widget logic", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => const MaterialApp(home: CustomHeaderBackgroundScreen());
}

void main() => runApp(const App());
```

#### Result

Here is how it is running on Chrome
[image: Code in action]

#### Note on Accessibility

Different screen sizes and system preferences on text size might make this design hard to accommodate for, especially for getting the text sized well with this right aligned style, so be aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the shapes using the CustomPaint widget together with BezierCurves. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60383699/how-to-draw-shapes-using-bezier-curves-in-a-flutter-custompainter) you can find out how to use BezierCurves with flutter.